# An error occurred while trying to run the script on device with IOS 8 and Xcode 6 UIAutomation

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

When I try to run a UI Automation script on the device Iphone 4s with iOS 8 with Xcode 6, I am getting the following error:
"An error occurred while trying to run the script."

[image]

While I tried the same script on IOS 7.1 and it's ran.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution on Apple forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1017776#1017776

There is a new setting under "Settings" -> "Developer" -> "UIAUTOMATATION" -> "Enable UIAutomatation".

It worked for me.